# Spring JavaConfig - Disabling Autowiring on @Bean Annotated Config Methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I am trying to convert some existing xml-based configurations to JavaConfig and I've run into a wall.

### `@Config` class:

```
@Configuration
@Import(TestContext.class)
public class BatchUsageReportJobTestContext {

    @Bean(name = "test.jobLauncher")
    public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncher(@Qualifier("reporting.job.usageReportJob") Job job, // From TestContext.class
                                            @Qualifier("test.simpleJobLauncher") JobLauncher jobLauncher) { // From TestContext.class
        JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);

        return jobLauncherTestUtils;
    }
}
```

`JobLauncherTestUtils` is a piece of spring-batch code:

### `org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils` (Snippet)

```
public class JobLauncherTestUtils {
  private Job job;

  @Autowired
  public Job setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
  }
}
```

The problem is that after my `@Bean` method has been called, and the setters invoked with the correct `@Qualifer` annotated beans, spring tries to `@Autowire` (which isn't `@Qualified`) in the fields it can find, overwriting the field I've set. Problem is that there is more than one bean of type `Job`, so I get the following:

```
... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: reporting.job.reportProcessing,reporting.job.summaryReport,reporting.job.usageReportJob
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
... 44 more
```

I can't think what the best thing to do is here. With XML config you can have as many beans as you want of any type and pick and choose the right one - this doesn't appear to be possible, or at least easy to accomplish.
What am I doing wrong? Ideally I'd like the @Bean annotated class to just register a bean - not do any magic. Setting `autowire=Autowire.NO` doesn't help either.

Comment: If bean is autowired by type maybe spring profiles might help You solve Your problem or split your test context into separate contexts with one bean of type `Job` defined i bet `TestContext` defines all three beans of type `Job` while test says it should depend only on `usageReportJob` am i right ?

Comment: Yes - there are multiple instances of `Job` defined, but I don't understand why it's so difficult to set one when there are multiple. This can be done easily with XML config.

Am I missing the point? Is the Autowire trying to enforce reduced scope?

Comment: The plain `@Autowire` tries to autowire bean by type, if You have 3 beans of the same type, which one should be autowired  ?

Comment: If you need multiple beans of the same type and that has `@Autowiring` that isn't going to work with JavaConfig...

Comment: @M.Deinum So there's no way to supply a qualifier to an bean that has plain `@Autowired`?

Comment: No because those are scanned by the `AutowireBeanPostProcessor`. The same would fail if you add a `<context:component-scan />` or `<context:annotation-config />` to your XML. As with that you indicate you want the `@Autowired` to be processed.

Comment: You can give priority to a bean to be autowired via the `@Priority` annotation which may allow you to choose the job to be autowired.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I don't think that's going to work, either. My understanding is that `@Order` and `@Priority` apply when injecting bound collections and won't just give you the highest priority item when you ask for one

Comment: @Priority dictates that the item annotated with it should be chosen during autowiring

Answer (score 0):

> Generally we uses annotation above `declaration` or above `getters`. So
>   try this as **:**

```
public class JobLauncherTestUtils {

  @Autowired
  private Job job;

  public Job setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible. This is a third-party library that I can't edit.